# Normalize the 3D skeleton data for deep learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, normalization

I have some 3D motion capture data for training a deep learning model, but the loss is too high so I need to apply normalization to adjust the input data.

The list below is the steps I am planning to do for the normalization:

1. **Set the skeleton's left sole to be the origin point (0, 0, 0)**
   All joint points (x, y, z) minus the left sole point(x<sub>ls</sub>, y<sub>ls</sub>, z<sub>ls</sub>)
2. **Set the skeleton's height as 1**
   Divide all the joint point y-axis values by the y-value of the head point
3. **Calculate the angle between the waist-line and x-axis line**
   Calculate the angle between the two lines, the waist-line (The line connected by the Left-waist point and Right-waist point), and the line parallel to the X-axis extending from the midpoint of the waist-line.
4. **Every joint point multiply with the rotation matrix**
   Multiply the rotation matrix with the y-axis(height axis) as the rotation axis (right-handed coordinate system: the value on the X-axis is greater on the right than on the left)
   The rotation matrix is obtained as follows:
   `[[cos_theta, 0, neg_sin_theta],`
   `[0, 1, 0],`
   `[sin_theta, 0, cos_theta]]`

From a mathematical perspective, I drew an image as shown below to depict the normalization by multiplying with a rotation matrix, hoping the skeleton can rotate with the waist and let the waist-line always be parallel with the x-axis :
[image: waist-line and rotation matrix]

Now I want to normalize the 3D skeleton coordinates by multiplying the rotation matrix:
(I tested 3 different rotation matrixes. The above mentioned rotation matrix produced very high distortion, so I tested with the matrix below and got a more reasonable rotation, which I don't know why...)

```
rotate_matrix =[[cos_theta, neg_sin_theta, 0], 
               [sin_theta, cos_theta, 0],
               [0, 0, 1]]
```

Got the result of normalization:
The normalization using this rotation matrix still produces weird result, but at least it seems to rotate with the height-axis as desired.

[image: Normalization with rotation matrix, weird result.]

The original skeleton movement:

[image: original skeleton movement]

Hope someone give some advice of this normalization, or provide other ideas to deal with 3D skeleton normalization.

Thank you in advance for your input.